# MediaProjection stops when starting a new Runnable from activity

Tags: android

I'm using an implementation of `android.media.projection.MediaProjection` to get images and it is working just fine. However when calling `myService.myRunnable.run()`  from `MainActivity`, the callback `onImageAvailable()` stop getting called. Where `myService` is a Foreground Service bound to the activity, and `myRunnable` a Runnable object member of `myService`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MyService myService;

ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        isServiceBounded = false;
        myService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        isServiceBounded = true;
        MyService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (MyService.LocalBinder) service;
        myService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
    }
};

public class ImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Log.d(TAG, "this is called for each new frame until the button is pressed");
           ...
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

button.setOnClickListener(views -> {
         myService.myRunnable.run()
    });

if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)) {
        startMyService();
        bindToMyService();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    myService.killMyRunnable();// -> myRunnable = null;
    stopMyService();
    unbindService(mConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ...
    if (running) ? return true : return false;

}


}
```

,

```
public class MyService extends Service {

IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
public MyRunnable myRunnable;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getServerInstance() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
 }

 ...
}
```

,

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {


 private void dummyWorkload(){
     Log.d(TAG, "dummyWorkload: isWorking");
     try {
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         dummyWorkload();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

@Override
public void run() {
    dummyWorkload();
  }
}
```

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code stops the `MediaProjection` because it invokes `myRunnable.run()` from the `MainThread`, therefore freezing the UI while the runnable is busy. For the projection to continue working it should be called from a separate Thread. To solve the issue, either `extends Thread` instead of `implements Runnable` interface or call the `Runnable` this way:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new myRunnable);
myThread.start();
```